# jQuery how to load some json records into a form fields?

Tags: jquery, json, forms, load, get

i have a json file:

```json
{
   "data":"Click",
   "size":"Here"
}
```

and a form:

```html
<form>
   First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
   Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form>
```

i was wondering what is the correct sintax for loading multiple json records into multiple form elements?? Something like a form that u want to u want to modify and the values get queered into those fields

i know i can use:

```js
$getJSON('link_to_json_file' function() {

});
```

but i'm stuck here
thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or if your data return was fieldname value pairs like:

```json
{"firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe"}
```

you could do it like:

```js
$.getJSON('url_to_file', function(data) {
    for (var i in data) {
        $('input[name="'+i+'"]').val(data[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.each(data, function(key, val) { });` instead of `for` will be better

Comment: why would it be better? benchmarks i've seen show that traversing with the native for loops is faster, particularly with large objects.

Comment: ok, may be it's a little bit faster, but `each` syntax looks like a normal iterator compared to native `for` with some things like `data[i]` and if you are not using very large objects I think you should use `each`

Comment: While the OP's example uses input, it should be noted that the provided code won't hit textareas. I would change this to `$('.form-class *[name="'+i+'"]').val(data[i]);` - Where `.form-class` is the form you're wanting to target.

Answer (score 2):

Could you take a look at the JQuery loadJSON plugin on the http://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/ ? On the page http://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/wiki/WorkingWithFormElements is explained how this plugin load JSON object into the form. You can also find one live example here http://jquery-load-json.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/edit.html?ID=17. I think that this is exactly what you need. Just create empty form and load json in the form using the following code:

```
$('form').loadJSON(data);
```

This plugin handles all form elements such as check boxes, select list radio buttons etc. If you use it you will need to download plugin from the http://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/source/browse/trunk/scripts/jquery.loadJSON.js.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use $.get like below;

```
$.get('your_file.[php/json]',function(d){
    $("input[name='firstname']").val(d.data);
    $("input[name='firstname']").val(d.size);
},'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what's wrong with `$.getJSON`? It works fine:

```
$.getJSON("1.json", function(data) {
  $('input[name="firstname"]').val(data["data"]);
  $('input[name="lastname"]').val(data["size"]);
});
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but i was looking for a more shorter version of the code, because i might have 20 input boxes