# Load sample JSON into Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms

I'm trying to integrate the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604729/jquery-how-to-load-some-json-records-into-a-form-fields/5604847#5604847) into my rails (3.1) application.

I have a basic form with some links at the bottom to load some sample data from a JSON file.

`app/views/users/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Load alice", "#" %>
<%= link_to "Load bob", "#" %>
```

`public fixtures/sample.json`

```
{ "name" : "alice", "email" : "alice@alice.com",
  "name" : "bob", "email" : "bob@bob.com" }
```

What would be the proper way to set up the links to load sample data into the form? I know I could just use an `onclick` event to call the js, but that would be very messy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check example here http://jsfiddle.net/8drhX/1/, instead of rendering links from rails I created them in javascript. It is more convenient way I think